# Could not load NIB in bundle ImageViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm getting this error while running simulator. The project was not created on this environment, not sure I'm missing a configuration setting.

> **Error**
>   2012-08-08 19:30:56.411 ACME[4068:f803] mItemArray.count: 2 2012-08-08 19:30:56.413 ACME[4068:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ImageViewCell''

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure the file is ticked for **Target Membership** in the **File Inspector**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set the "files owner" in the NIB file to the owner you are setting in code.  The NIB loader will fail like this when it cant link the objects in the NIB to the right root owner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: go into IB for the NIB you are trying to load.  Select the files owner object, then check the class name.  Im sure its not the class you are trying to load the NIB into.  They have to match.

Answer (score 0):

The name after "loadNibNamed:" must be the name of the nib file (in project navigator on the left side of the screen), sometimes people write there 'cell identifier' that writes  from the start in CellForRowAtIndexPath (static NSString ...).

May be your problem in this little fault?